# "sudo cd ..." one-liner?

Tags: command-line, sudo

Occasionally I want to `cd` into a directory where my user does not have permission, so I resort to `sudo`.

The obvious command `sudo cd somedir` doesn't work:

```
$ sudo mkdir test
$ sudo chmod go-rxw test
$ ls -l
drwx------ 2 root     root  [...snip...] test
$ cd test
-bash: cd: test: Permission denied
$ sudo cd test
sudo: cd: command not found
```

Using `sudo su` works:

```
$ sudo su
# cd test
```

Is it possible to make this into a one-liner? (Not a big deal, just idle curiosity :)

The variations I tried didn't work:

```
$ sudo "cd test"
sudo: cd: command not found
$ sudo -i cd test
-bash: line 0: cd: test: No such file or directory
$ sudo -s cd test
```

The last one doesn't give an error, but it cd's within a new shell that exits by the end of the line, so it doesn't actually take me anywhere.

Can someone enlighten me as to why this happens? Why is `sudo cd` not found, when for example `sudo ls ...` works fine?

Comment: BTW, `sudo -i` is preferred over `sudo su`, otherwise the user's env vars will be [carried over](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RootSudo#Special_notes_on_sudo_and_shells).

Comment: @Sparhawk The user may not *want* an environment that simulates an initial login shell (`sudo -i`). But then it should still be unnecessary to use `sudo su`, as there is `sudo -s`. Running a root shell but *not* simulating an initial login shell is a common enough operation, and is considered reasonable enough, that `sudo` supports it officially with the `-s` option. Note also that running `sudo -i` followed by `cd dir`, when `dir` is a *relative path* that was *originally* correct, usually fails, as unlike `sudo -s`, `sudo -i` changes the current directory to the target user's home directory.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Theoretically, the problem is that if you don't have execute rights to a directory, you shouldn't be able to read the contents of the directory. Now suppose you could do what you wanted:

```
user@desktop:/$ sudo cd restricted-dir
user@desktop:/restricted-dir$ ls
file1 file2
```

As you can see, you entered the directory using sudo privileges, then, when sudo returns, you become a user again, and you are in a directory where you normally shouldn't be.

Technically, the problem is the following.

```
sudo cd restricted-dir
```

`cd` is a shell built-in, not a command.

```
sudo cd -i restricted-dir
```

You are probably in /root, but it would have the same problem as with the next one.

```
sudo cd -s restricted-dir
```

You open a new root shell, cd into the directory, then exit the root shell, and return to where you began.

All in all, the only solution is to open a root shell and keep it open while you are in that directory.

Comment: Technically, `cd` is a "shell builtin command" (according to `man bash`).

Comment: If this was the case @petersohn, then why would shell promt `cd: command not found`, It shows no permission issue.   And I don't think `shell builtin` is the particular reason either, because `sudo echo` works fine, while echo is also `shell builtin`

Answer (score 5):

```
sudo sh -c "cd restricted-dir; some-other-command"
```

i.e.

```
sudo sh -c "cd /root/restricted-dir; ls -l"
```

the key piece is "sh -c" which I use quite often to run a chain of commands in the same shell context/process.

Comment: Using `&&` instead of `;` will prevent the command from being executed if the change directory operation fails. In other words:  `sudo sh -c "cd restricted-dir && some-other-command"`